# Sort Through Array Excluding Nil

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I am attempting to sort an array which includes variables which are nil.

```
class TestArray {
    var a: String? = nil
    var b: String? = nil
    init(a: String?, b: String?) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}

let first = TestArray(a: "xxx", b: "yyy")
let second = TestArray(a: "zzz", b: "zzz")
let third = TestArray(a: "aaa", b: nil)

var array = [first, second, third]
array.sort(by: {($0.a as String!) > ($1.a as String!)})

array.sort(by: {($0.b as String!) > ($1.b as String!)}) // Throws an error
```

How can I sort by `b` and leave the third TestArray with b = nil at the end of the array?
Also I would like to sort through all b and then for the arrays in which b = nil sort the remaining by a.

Comment: How would you like nil to compare with non-nil values?

Comment: If some of the TestArray have "b = nil" I would like to take these and sort by "a".

Comment: What rule are you following to sort the elements exactly?

Comment: array.sort(by: {($0.a as String!) > ($1.a as String!)})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should cover the situations you want without having to iterate more than once (which is expensive)

```
array.sort { (lessThan, item) -> Bool in

    switch (lessThan.a, lessThan.b, item.a, item.b) {
    // if bs exist, use that comparison
    case (_, .some(let lessThanB), _, .some(let itemB)):
        return lessThanB < itemB
    // if bs don't exist by as do, use that comparison
    case (.some(let lessThanA), .none, .some(let itemA), .none):
        return lessThanA < itemA
    // if one item has a value but the other doesn't, the item with the value should be first
    case (_, .some(_), _, .none), (.some(_), _, .none, _ ):
        return true

    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, just fixed the second case to (I think) match your requirements better.

Comment: This is needlessly complex, and doesn't scale for many properties. Also `.none` can be short handed to `nil`, and `.some(let x)` can be shorthanded to `x?`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's (in my opinion) the best way:

First, I define a `<` operator for `String?` instances.
It operates for the specification that  `nil` compares as less than any other string, so it'll appear *first* in sorting order.

```
fileprivate func <(a: String?, b: String?) -> Bool {
    switch (a, b) {
        case (nil, nil): return false
        case (nil, _?): return true
        case (_?, nil): return false
        case (let a?, let b?): return a < b

    }
}
```

Next, I wrote a sorting predicate that uses that operator. It works for the specification that instances are to be sorted first by their `a`. If those are equal, ties are broken by sorting by their `b`.

```
struct TestStruct {
    var a: String?
    var b: String?
}

let input = [  
    TestStruct(a: "xxx", b: "yyy"),
    TestStruct(a: "zzz", b: "zzz"),
    TestStruct(a: "aaa", b: nil)
]

let output = input.sorted { lhs, rhs in
    if lhs.a != rhs.a { return lhs.a < rhs.a } // first sort by a
    if lhs.b != rhs.b { return lhs.b < rhs.b } // then sort by b

    return true
}

print(output)
//[
//    TempCode.TestStruct(a: Optional("aaa"), b: nil),
//    TempCode.TestStruct(a: Optional("xxx"), b: Optional("yyy")),
//    TempCode.TestStruct(a: Optional("zzz"), b: Optional("zzz"))
//]
```

*I made `TestStruct` a struct just so I can use the synthesized initializer and automatic print behaviour. It'll work just the same if it's a class.

If you'll be comparing `TestStruct` a lot, and it makes sense for there to be a standard order to comparing it, then it's best you add conformance to `Comparable`. Doing so also requires conformance to `Equatable`:

```
extension TestStruct: Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: TestStruct, rhs: TestStruct) -> Bool {
        return
            lhs.a == rhs.a &&
            lhs.b == rhs.b
    }
}

extension TestStruct: Comparable {
    public static func <(lhs: TestStruct, rhs: TestStruct) -> Bool {
        if lhs.a != rhs.a { return lhs.a < rhs.a } // first sort by a
        if lhs.b != rhs.b { return lhs.b < rhs.b } // then sort by b

        return true
    }
}
```

Now you can sort your array easily with the sorting behaviour specified by `TestStruct`:

```
let output = input.sorted()
```

[You can see it in action here.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5807dd7bb759857f9f316ae0)

Comment: In a constrained circumstance this works really well!, but since < is a global function every single comparison of 2 String optionals will be compared that way, which could be undesired.

Comment: The other option would be to make TestArray adhere to Comparable, then you could just use the built in sort() functionality.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ You're right, I forgot to add the access specifiier. I'm actually in the process of writing my answer about making `TestStruct` comparable.

Comment: Indeed, conforming `TestStruct` to `Comparable` should be the best approach.

Comment: Thanks to all, awesome feedback, I love the discussions!

Comment: As I already wrote in the comment to you under my own answer, nice job! I believe there's a typo in the `==` function, however (I believe `lhs.a == rhs.b` should be `lhs.a = rhs.a`).

Comment: @dfri yup nice catch!

Comment: Might be worth noting that (since `a` and `b` properties are optionals), the returns in `TestStruct`:s `<` function compiles only due to the `fileprivate` `<` function for optional `String` instances. Imho, I believe the best approach would be to encapsulate all `Comparable` logic of `TestStruct` within `TestStruct`, not depending on global (although fileprivate) functions. This could be easily remedied, however, by moving the global `<` method into `TestStruct` as a private `(String, String) -> Bool` helper (non-operator) method used for fulfulling the conformance to `Comparable`.

Comment: @dfri The `<` operator can't be a member of `TestStruct`, because that requires at least one of its arguments to be of type `TestStruct` (but obviously we need both to be `String?`). I don't know of any better ways. The operator will likely reside in some utilities file, where it can be used application-wide (assuming `nil`-first behaviour is wanted across the board.

Comment: Note that I described that the `<` global `String?` function could be included as a _non-operator helper function_ in `TestStruct`, after which `return lhs.a < rhs.a` simply changes into e.g. `return privateHelper(lhs.a, rhs.a)`. (I see no reason to keep the global function as it's ever only used within the `<` member function of `TestStruct`).

Comment: @dfri Yeah, I had considered that, but found little benefit over a `fileprivate <`, certainly not enough to warrant deviation from common swift syntax

Answer (score 1):

In case you needn't necessarily sort in place, you could simply apply the "algorithm" you describe in a brute-force fashion to sort `array` using several `filter` followed `sorted` for the subset arrays.

"Algorithm":

- Primarily sort by `b` property, given that it is not `nil`.
- For elements where the `b` property is `nil`, sort by `a` property.
- Leave elements where both `a` and `b` are `nil` at the end of the sorted array.

E.g.:

```
// lets set up a more interesting example
let first = TestArray(a: "xxx", b: "yyy")
let second = TestArray(a: "ccc", b: nil)
let third = TestArray(a: "aaa", b: nil)
let fourth = TestArray(a: "zzz", b: "zzz")
let fifth = TestArray(a: "bbb", b: nil)

var array = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth]

let sorted = array.filter { $0.b != nil }.sorted { $0.b! < $1.b! } +
             array.filter { $0.b == nil && $0.a != nil }.sorted { $0.a! < $1.a! } +
             array.filter { $0.b == nil && $0.a == nil }

sorted.enumerated().forEach { print("\($0): b: \($1.b), a: \($1.a)") }
/* 0: b: Optional("yyy"), a: Optional("xxx")
   1: b: Optional("zzz"), a: Optional("zzz")
   2: b: nil, a: Optional("aaa")
   3: b: nil, a: Optional("bbb")
   4: b: nil, a: Optional("ccc")             */
```

Comment: FYI, you're iterating over the array ~6 times. At a small scale it won't matter, but the performance will decrease 6x as the array scales.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Hence the _"brute-force fashion"_ description included in the introduction ;) I believe the most important point is that the asymptotic complexity of this method will still depend solely on the complexity of the sorter (but w.r.t. to your single-pass solution, some constant worse in actual iterations, but with no effect on asymptotic behaviour).

Comment: @dfri The problem with considering only asymptotic performance is that we don't live in the realm of the infinite sizes :p

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov the problem with pre-mature performance analysis is that we don't live in the realm of commonly running into HPC bottlenecks (until a profiler tells us so) :p (naturally worth a prompt though, +1 @ PEEJWEEJ initial comment). (But that aside, your `Comparable` and `Equatable` method would be the answer I would choose to proceed with myself, if I were to visit this Q&A!)